# SQLAlchemy ORM - Deferring constraint checking

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a unique constraint on one of my tables that I would like to defer, which is something Postgresql supports from what I understand, but I can't seem to find where I can tell my operation to do so in SQLAlchemy when using the ORM (in general, not just specifically this case).  I am using the `bulk_update_mappings()` function, and the constraint is the 2nd under `__table_args__`.  Is this something I need to use SQLAlchemy Core or create my own SQL statement to achieve?

```
class Question(Base):
    QuestionType = enum.Enum('QuestionType', 'mcq')
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Enum(_QuestionType), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String, nullable=False)
    question_order = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    question_set_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('question_sets.id', ondelete='cascade'), nullable=False)

    question_set = relationship('QuestionSet', back_populates='questions')

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('question_set_id', 'description'),
        UniqueConstraint('question_set_id', 'question_order', deferrable=True)
    )
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'question',
        'polymorphic_on': type,
    }

#from another class
def reorder(self, new_order, db):
    order = [{'id':i, 'question_order': index} for index, i in enumerate(new_order)]
    db.bulk_update_mappings(Question, order)
    db.commit()
```

Comment: Run `db.execute('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED')` before your bulk operation in order to defer all deferrable constraints in the current transaction: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html. You could opt to defer the unique constraint only, if you know its name.

Comment: This works.  I gave my constraint a name and did `db.execute('SET CONSTRAINTS unique_order DEFERRED;')`

Comment: Related, though not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533592/how-to-set-constraints-deferred-in-sqlalchemy-core, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210453/how-to-set-constraints-deferred-in-sqlalchemy-expression-language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that `db` is your session instance, run

```
db.execute('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED')
```

before your bulk operation in order to [defer all deferrable constraints](http://postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html) in the *current transaction*. Note that [not all constraints are deferrable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680817/set-constraints-all-deferred-not-working-as-expected-in-postgresql-9-3), even if they're declared as such. You could opt to defer the unique constraint only, if you know its name, such as *unique_order*:

```
def reorder(self, new_order, db):
    order = [{'id':i, 'question_order': index} for index, i in enumerate(new_order)]
    db.execute('SET CONSTRAINTS unique_order DEFERRED')
    db.bulk_update_mappings(Question, order)
    db.commit()
```

Comment: After the bulk operation, is it necessary to `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE`? Or does that happen automatically following the `commit()`?

Comment: `SET CONSTRAINTS` controls constraints within the transaction, so after a commit its effects are gone.